# How do I get matched characters from Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a data URI pattern of `data:\w+/\w+;\w+,\w+` in Python. How do I retain each match to use later (essentially, each of the `w+` pieces)?

Comment: I don't mean to sound flippant here, but have you tried reading the documentation?  If so, is there a part you don't understand? If you could tell us that it might help us shape our explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capture them into groups, i.e. `data:(\w+)/(\w+);(\w+),(\w+)`. You can then use [`m.group(x)`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) or [`m.groups()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) (where `m` is a match object) to obtain them (note that group 0 is the entire matched string).

Answer (score 2):

You need groups. From the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

> (...)
>       Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched later in the string with the \number special sequence, described below. To match the literals '(' or ')', use ( or ), or enclose them inside a character class: [(] [)].

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be `r'data:(\w+)/(\w+);(\w+),(\w+)'` or something beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in groups. I don't know Python, but this is the same in every language.
You group things in RegEx using brackets.

`data:(\w+)/(\w+);(\w+),(\w+)`

Then, using Python RegExp functions, get the groups that match.